# Size difference of output files from FFMPEG and NVENC rendering

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, size, nvenc

For this:

```
NVEncC64.exe --avhw -i "PATH\FILE (SRC).MP4" -c "av1" --cbr 1500 --audio-codec aac --audio-bitrate 64 -o "PATH\FILE (AV1).MP4"
```

I used the NVEncC (x64) -Encoder Version 7.21,
but for this:

```
ffmpeg -i "PATH\FILE (SRC).MP4" -c:v av1_nvenc -b:v 1500k -b:a 64k -y "PATH\FILE (AV1).MP4"
```

I do not know which version is used.

The result from a test with the same file ("PATH\FILE (SRC).MP4"), the size of the rendered files ("PATH\FILE (AV1).MP4") were 260303 and 272186 respectively. So now I'm curios whether the first is lacking quality, or what it is that is causing the difference in size?

Comment: Two different encoders, very different source code; and you expect the output to be the same?  That will not happen...